# can-i-deploy fails on first new consumer build

Tags: java, spring-boot, jenkins-pipeline, pact

I created pipeline in jenkins for building new consumer. In this pipeline after I build new consumer and publish new pact to pact-broker I invoke 'mvn pact:can-i-deploy -Dpacticipant=consumer-name -Dlatest=true' and it fails due to it's new contract not verified yet by the provider.
Is there only one way?

1. build first time without invoking 'can-i-deploy'
2. build provider and verify new contract
3. after that build new consumer always with 'can-i-deploy' enabled

or is there a way to prevent failure for new consumer when it's contract was not verified ever?

or maybe I need to trigger building provider each time when build consumer with changed contract?

Answer (score 1):

From Pact's point of view, it doesn't know that the reason it can't let you deploy is that you're adding a new contract for an existing (working) system. All it sees is "no provider has verified this".

Your best bet is to have a "jail break" option. At Pactflow, we have a `SKIP_CAN_I_DEPLOY` environment variable that can be enabled to skip this step entirely for certain scenarios.

Also I would encourage you to read https://docs.pactflow.io/docs/workshops/ci-cd/. Using "latest" is not a great idea in most cases, and you probably also want to include the tag to denote which environment you want to deploy to.